# How to programmatically reset jQuery plugin 'intl-tel-input' to default placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, property-placeholder, intl-tel-input

When using int-tel-input jQuery plugin, one sometimes needs to reset the placeholder to default. Is there a method like :

```
$('input').intlTelInput('setPlaceholder', 'myDefaultPlaceholder' );
```

which should be called after :

```
$('input').intlTelInput('setCountry', 'myDefaultCountry' );
$('input').intlTelInput('setPlaceholderNumberType', 'MOBILE' );
```

The workaround I think of is :

```
$('input').val( "" );
$('input').attr( "placeholder", "defaultPlaceholder" );
$('input').intlTelInput('setCountry', 'myDefaultCountry' );
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset it if the `input` has a value inside?

Answer (score 1):

Oh mine. After much trial-and-error, I just discovered that the method I was looking for is redundant after all. First setting the value of the input element to empty string and then calling 'setCountry' api method did the trick.

```
$('input').val( "" );
$('input').intlTelInput('setCountry', 'myDefaultCountry' );
```

What stopped if from working the first time was the space I inserted in the value like so `$('input').val( " " );` instead of `$('input').val( "" );` And since the plugin found a blank space as the value of the input element, the placeholder did not show up.

Just in case anyone may find this helpful.